# Command objects designing

Tags: design-patterns

I have two command classes which are identical except for the events they fire when they finish their execution. I am wondering is there an elegant way to have a single class which does the work and fires the appropriate event. I don't want to put an `if` condition in the code as I might have one more command with the similar requirement in the futute. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Make the Event you fire a parameter of your class. Or so to say, make your command class generic. So, when you should fire an event, just fire the one you specified.

Answer (score 0):

DDD influences your commands to be only packaged action information - they only have data in them. CommandHandler's on the other hand contain all the necessary logic for the 'Command' execution, including list of raised events.

May be it's worth exploring.